# System.exit(0) vs JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java, swing, jframe, exit

Is there any difference between the two. I was reading an article ( http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17933 ) about that you should always use

```
System.exit(0);
```

Currently I use

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
```

The article says that even for a Java Swing Application you should add a listener `WindowAdapter` and and call `System.exit()` inside its method `windowClosing(WindowEvent e)`.

Is there any difference? Is one method better then the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the JFrame code, it does:

```
 protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
        super.processWindowEvent(e);

        if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
            switch(defaultCloseOperation) {
              ...
          case EXIT_ON_CLOSE:
                  // This needs to match the checkExit call in
                  // setDefaultCloseOperation
        System.exit(0);
        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, it's exactly the same thing. I would just set EXIT_ON_CLOSE if that's what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering System.exit(0) is in the JFrame coding, either would work.